# Encode and stream raw audio over RTP/RTSP using FDK-AAC

Tags: rtsp, rtp, aac, sdp, mpeg-4

**EDITS ADDED AT END*****

I am looking for the 'simplest' way to configure an aac encoder (`FDK-AAC` library), sdp header, and RTP headers so that the minimum viable RTP audio stream can be played. (To avoid subjectivity, by simplest, I mean requires the least amount of manual overhead/config and setup work to get streaming to a player like `ffplay` or `vlc`)

I am getting single channel 16b PCM data as input. I have already confirmed I am able to encode that and dump the bitstream to an aac file which plays fine with `ffplay` using the following configuration options for `fdk-aac` and a pretty standard encoding loop:

```
aacEncoder_SetParam(aac_handle, AACENC_AOT, AOT_AAC_LC);
aacEncoder_SetParam(aac_handle, AACENC_BITRATE, 96000);
aacEncoder_SetParam(aac_handle, AACENC_SAMPLERATE, 16000);
aacEncoder_SetParam(aac_handle, AACENC_CHANNELMODE, MODE_1);
aacEncoder_SetParam(aac_handle, AACENC_BANDWIDTH, 0);
aacEncoder_SetParam(aac_handle, AACENC_CHANNELORDER, 1);
aacEncoder_SetParam(aac_handle, AACENC_AFTERBURNER, 1);
aacEncoder_SetParam(aac_handle, AACENC_SBR_MODE, 0);
aacEncoder_SetParam(aac_handle, AACENC_SBR_RATIO, 0);
aacEncoder_SetParam(aac_handle, AACENC_TRANSMUX, TT_MP4_LOAS);
aacEncoder_SetParam(aac_handle, AACENC_SIGNALING_MODE, 0);
```

I have also confirmed that I am able to stream the raw PCM data to ffplay using the following SDP and RTP header setup:

```
char sdp[] = "v=0\r\n"
"o=- 0 0 IN IP4 127.0.0.1\r\n"
"s=Unnamed\r\n"
"c=IN IP4 127.0.0.1\r\n"
"a=recvonly\r\n"
"a=charset:UTF-8\r\n"
"m=audio 50040 RTP/AVP 100\r\n"
"a=rtpmap:100 L16/16000\r\n";

// Header setup (in send loop):
hdr.flags = 0x80;
hdr.mk_pt = 0x80 | 100;
hdr.sq_nb = htons(rtp_packet_count);
hdr.ts = htonl(rtp_timestamp_audio);
hdr.ssrc = htonl(10);
...
// packet count and timestamp updated later
```

I have not had any success trying to stream AAC with RT(S)P however, despite different encoder configurations (mostly changing the `transmux` param to try `TT_MP4_LATM_MCP1` and others), SDP packets, and RTP headers. Most recent example of an SDP/RTP header I have tried to use is:

```
char sdp_aac[] =
"v=0\r\n"
"o=- 0 0 IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\n"
"s=Unnamed\r\n"
"c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\n"
"a=recvonly\r\n"
"a=charset:UTF-8\r\n"
"m=audio 0 RTP/AVP 97\r\n"
"a=rtpmap:97 MP4A-LATM/16000/1\r\n"
"a=fmtp:97 cpresent=1; config=400028100000\r\n";

// Header setup (in send loop):
hdr.flags = 0x80;
hdr.mk_pt = 0x80 | 97;
hdr.sq_nb = htons(rtp_packet_count);
hdr.ts = htonl(rtp_timestamp_audio);
hdr.ssrc = htonl(10);
```

This results in `ffplay` outputting a long dump of errors as long as I leave the stream trying to play:

```
[rtsp @ 0x7f79e4000bc0] RTP MP4A-LATM with in-band configuration is not implemented. Update your FFmpeg version to the newest one from Git. If the problem still occurs, it means that your file has a feature which has not been implemented.
[rtsp @ 0x7f79e4000bc0] If you want to help, upload a sample of this file to ftp://upload.ffmpeg.org/incoming/ and contact the ffmpeg-devel mailing list. (ffmpeg-devel@ffmpeg.org)
[aac @ 0x7f79e40046c0] Number of bands (31) exceeds limit (16)./0   
Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://10.66.171.29':
  Metadata:
    title           : Unnamed
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Audio: aac (LC), 16000 Hz, mono, fltp
[rtsp @ 0x7f79e4000bc0] Malformed LATM packet
    Last message repeated 1 times
[aac @ 0x7f79e40b6680] Number of bands (31) exceeds limit (16).
[rtsp @ 0x7f79e4000bc0] Malformed LATM packet
    Last message repeated 1 times
[aac @ 0x7f79e40b6680] channel element 3.4 is not allocated
[rtsp @ 0x7f79e4000bc0] Malformed LATM packet
[aac @ 0x7f79e40b6680] channel element 3.4 is not allocated
    Last message repeated 2 times
[aac @ 0x7f79e40b6680] Sample rate index in program config element does not match the sample rate index configured by the container.
[aac @ 0x7f79e40b6680] decode_pce: Input buffer exhausted before END element found
[rtsp @ 0x7f79e4000bc0] Malformed LATM packet 0KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
    Last message repeated 1 times
[rtsp @ 0x7f79e4000bc0] Malformed LATM packet 0KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
    Last message repeated 1 times
[rtsp @ 0x7f79e4000bc0] Malformed LATM packet 0KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
    Last message repeated 1 times
[aac @ 0x7f79e40b6680] Number of bands (31) exceeds limit (16).
[aac @ 0x7f79e40b6680] channel element 2.10 is not allocated
[aac @ 0x7f79e40b6680] skip_data_stream_element: Input buffer exhausted before END element found
[aac @ 0x7f79e40b6680] SBR was found before the first channel element.
[aac @ 0x7f79e40b6680] Reserved bit set.
...
And On
```

and vlc reports simply `main decoder error: buffer deadlock prevented`.

I am not sure if I am messing up the transport type or something else in the encoder (see the first ffplay error message) or the header/SDP OR the way I packetize and send the data (likely some combination). I am essentially brand new to AAC/streaming/RTP/RTSP and in the "throw things at the wall" stage so I am hoping someone can help me figure out the correct encoder settings and SDP params required for the simplest audio stream ffplay or vlc will accept.

I have read through RFC 5691, 6416, and 3550 but there is so much extra info I am a bit overwhelmed by the configurability of all this as well.

Happy to edit the question if there is any more info I can provide!

### Edit 1

I am now able to 'stream' (albeit poorly/with gaps and glitches but recognizable) using the following configs:

```
// Encoder config: (same as above if not listed)
aacEncoder_SetParam(aac_handle, AACENC_TRANSMUX, TT_MP4_ADTS)
// SDP:
char sdp_aac[] =
"v=0\r\n"
"o=- 0 0 IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\n"
"s=Unnamed\r\n"
"c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\n"
"a=recvonly\r\n"
"a=charset:UTF-8\r\n"
"m=audio 50040 RTP/AVP 97\r\n"
"a=rtpmap:97 mpeg4-generic/16000/1\r\n"
"a=fmtp:97 config=1408\r\n"; // config hex from encoder config binary
// RTP Packet Headers:
hdr.flags = 0x80;
hdr.mk_pt = 0x80 | 97;
hdr.sq_nb = htons(rtp_packet_count);
hdr.ts = htonl(rtp_timestamp_audio);
hdr.ssrc = htonl(10);
```

However, with ffplay, I now get a single repeated error and no audio: `[rtsp @ 0x7fc3d8000bc0] Error parsing AU headers`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue I was encountering was the lack of 'AU Headers' in the stream ([Explained here in RFC 3640](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3640#section-3.2.1)). Overall, the settings I needed to get the stream working were:

**Encoder config:**

```
aacEncoder_SetParam(aac_handle, AACENC_AOT, AOT_AAC_LC) != AACENC_OK)
aacEncoder_SetParam(aac_handle, AACENC_BITRATE, 96000) != AACENC_OK)
aacEncoder_SetParam(aac_handle, AACENC_BITRATEMODE, 0) != AACENC_OK)
aacEncoder_SetParam(aac_handle, AACENC_SAMPLERATE, 16000) != AACENC_OK)
aacEncoder_SetParam(aac_handle, AACENC_CHANNELMODE, MODE_1) != AACENC_OK)
aacEncoder_SetParam(aac_handle, AACENC_BANDWIDTH, 0) != AACENC_OK)
aacEncoder_SetParam(aac_handle, AACENC_CHANNELORDER, 1) != AACENC_OK)
aacEncoder_SetParam(aac_handle, AACENC_AFTERBURNER, 0) != AACENC_OK)
aacEncoder_SetParam(aac_handle, AACENC_SBR_MODE, 0) != AACENC_OK)
aacEncoder_SetParam(aac_handle, AACENC_SBR_RATIO, 0) != AACENC_OK)
aacEncoder_SetParam(aac_handle, AACENC_TRANSMUX, TT_MP4_ADTS) != AACENC_OK)
aacEncoder_SetParam(aac_handle, AACENC_SIGNALING_MODE, 0) != AACENC_OK)
```

**SDP (note added `*Length` params for AU header):**

```
"v=0\r\n"
"o=- 0 0 IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\n"
"s=Unnamed\r\n"
"c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\n"
"a=recvonly\r\n"
"a=charset:UTF-8\r\n"
"m=audio 50040 RTP/AVP 98\r\n"
"a=rtpmap:98 mpeg4-generic/16000/1\r\n"
"a=fmtp:98 mode=AAC-hbr; config=1408; sizeLength=13; indexLength=3; IndexDeltaLength=3;\r\n";
```

**RTP Header:**

```
hdr.flags = 0x80;
hdr.mk_pt = 0x80 | 98;
hdr.sq_nb = htons(stream->cnt);
hdr.ts = htonl(timestamp);
hdr.ssrc = htonl(10);
```

**AU Header: (The missing piece):**

```
typedef struct{
  uint16_t  header_len = 0x1000; // Size of this structure not counting this field
  uint16_t  au_size_idx; // First 13b are the size of the AU in bytes, last 3b are apparently ignored (RFC 3640 s3.3.6)
} au_header_aac_t;
    
uint16_t au_size = this_len << 3;
au_hdr.au_size_idx = ntohs(au_size);
```